# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}-(x^2+1)^{1/3}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}-(x^4+1)^{1/5}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}-(x^2+1)^{1/3}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}-(x^4+1)^{1/5}}$$

What I did to solve this problem is here

[image]

I tried to multiply by $1/x$ the numerator and denominator and I got a limit of $1$ at the end, but I am not sure if what I got is right.

Comment: Why do you doubt your result?

Comment: I have never done a limit like this one so I am not sure if what I did is right

Comment: Why not show a bit more of your development?  If you do so, we can help verify if you proceeded correctly.

Comment: Ok,I am going to do it inmediately

Answer (score 2):

Your answer $1$ is correct. 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}-(x^2+1)^{1/3}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}-(x^4+1)^{1/5}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}-x^{2/3}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/3}}{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^{1/4}-x^{4/5}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^{1/5}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}-\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/3}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^{1/4}-\frac{1}{x^{1/5}}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^{1/5}}$$
$$=\frac{1-0}{1-0}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}-(x^2+1)^{1/3}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}-(x^4+1)^{1/5}} \sim \frac{x-x^{2/3}}{x-x^{4/5}}=\frac{1-x^{-1/3}}{1-x^{-1/5}}$$
So $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}-(x^2+1)^{1/3}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}-(x^4+1)^{1/5}} =1$$